# How to use URI DNS record with HTTP?

Tags: networking

I'm trying to use a URI record with HTTP https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI_record

On Cloudflare I put `sub` in `Name` and `https://example.com/page/` in `Content` yet if I go to `https://sub.example.net` it says `curl: (6) Could not resolve host: sub.example.net`

Comment: Nobody uses this record type.

Comment: @MichaelHampton: That's so true. Should we add a *Usage* section to the Wikipedia article stating that? :D

Comment: MIT Kerberos does support this now: 'As of MIT krb5 1.15, clients can also locate KDCs in DNS through URI records...Limitations with the SRV record format may result in extra DNS queries...The URI record can convey more information...with a single query' from [KDC Discovery](https://web.mit.edu/kerberos/krb5-latest/doc/admin/realm_config.html#kdc-discovery)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### The purpose

The purpose of RFC 7553 `URI` records is not to replace [HTTP redirection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Redirections), but to complement S-NAPTR ([5.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7553#section-5.2)), replace U-NAPTR ([5.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7553#section-5.3)) and replace `SRV` ([5.4](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7553#section-5.4)) record types. I think the intended purpose is best expressed in [section 2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7553#section-2):

> In general, it is expected that URI records will be used by clients
> for applications where the relevant protocol to be used is known,
> but, for example, an extra abstraction is needed in order to separate
> a domain name from a point of service (as addressed by the URI).  One
> example of such a situation is when an organization has many domain
> names but only one official web page.

Just like with the `SRV` records, this requires that an application is designed to use `URI` records for finding this information. **Web browsers aren't following URI records** and won't even try and resolve them. The HTTP protocol doesn't utilize `URI` records at all, and web browsers are  following the protocol.

### Usage

As Michael Hampton mentions in comments, neither have I ever seen a service, a protocol or an application using `URI` records. E.g. the Wikipedia article for SRV records has [Usage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SRV_record#Usage) section listing some protocols that are utilizing the `SRV` resource record type, but the article for `URI` records doesn't even have a similar section as of July 2020. ***Nobody uses this record type.***

### The syntax

The [section 2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7553#section-2) continues:

> Applications need to know the specific service to prepend the hostname with.

and there's an example given in [section 5.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7553#section-5.1):

> An organization has the domain names `example.com` and `example.net`,
> and their FTP archive is at `ftp://ftp1.example.com/public`.  Given
> the service name `ftp` and transport protocol `tcp` (from the IANA
> "Service Name and Transport Protocol Port Number Registry"), the
> following URI resource records could be made available in the
> respective zones (example.com and example.net):
>
> ```
> $ORIGIN example.com.
> _ftp._tcp    IN URI 10 1 "ftp://ftp1.example.com/public"
>
> $ORIGIN example.net.
> _ftp._tcp    IN URI 10 1 "ftp://ftp1.example.com/public"
> ```

Let's **imagine for a moment** that web browsers had adopted RFC 7553 `URI` records. In that case, the `URI` record for HTTP service for `sub.example.net` would be under `_http._tcp.sub.example.net`:

```
_http._tcp.sub.example.net. IN URI 10 1 "https://example.com/page/"
```

What you had configured wouldn't have a chance to work as expected because of syntax error.

### How to achieve your desired functionality

In general you would need to create a HTTP/HTTPS service on `sub.example.net` that replies with either `301 Moved Permanently` ([RFC 7231, 6.4.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.4.2)) or `302 Found` ([6.4.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.4.3)) and `Location` ([7.1.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-7.1.2)) containing the `https://example.com/page/`; **in short, [HTTP redirection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Redirections)**.

With Cloudflare, HTTP redirections can be configured using [Cloudflare Page Rules](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/218411427-Understanding-and-Configuring-Cloudflare-Page-Rules-Page-Rules-Tutorial-).

Comment: FreeIPA 4.9.8 is now using URI records for KDC discovery: https://www.freeipa.org/page/Releases/4.9.8#highlights-in-4-9-8 (8968: Add URI records for KDC)